# Accesso ai dati di microfono UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to access the microphone data, and I found this: [Audio device information properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-device-information-properties) but I can not figure out how to get to `"System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRationInDb"`.

Some examples of help? Every suggestion is welcome!

This is what I did with your example and finding the id with the help of Windows-universal-samples-master, but I stop at the deviceInfo variable.

Code:

```
private async void btnMicrophone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //try
        //{
            string interfaceId = @"308B60E6-205A-4CAE-B22E-10BD99A22B52";
            string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb", "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SensitivityInDbfs" };
            DeviceInformation deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(interfaceId, requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.DeviceInterface);
            var allpro = deviceInfo.Properties.AsParallel();
            foreach (var one in allpro)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(one);
            }
            var result = deviceInfo.Properties.TryGetValue("System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb", out SignalToNoiseRatioInDb);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SignalToNoiseRatioInDb);
        //}
        //catch { }
}
```

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z027C.png).

Comment: There's an extra 'n' in `Ratio*n*` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry peter but I just can not get to "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRationInDb" could you give me some help with an example?

Comment: Try removing the 'n' from the word "Ration" - - it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

> but I just can not get to "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRationInDb" could you give me some help with an example?

As @Peter Torr mentioned, the property should be [`System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt842877(v=vs.85).aspx), not `System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRationInDb`, remove `n` from the word `Ration`.

If you just don't know how to get the [Device information properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties), please try to reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing). Pay attention that `System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb` is belong to [Windows Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx), not a namespace.

The [`DeviceInformation.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation#Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation_Properties) store containing well-known values as well as additional properties that can be specified during device enumeration.
Maybe you could try the following code snippet,

```
try
{
    string interfaceId = @"...";
    string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb", "System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SensitivityInDbfs" };
    DeviceInformation deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(interfaceId, requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.DeviceInterface); 
    object SignalToNoiseRatioInDb; 
    var allpro = deviceInfo.Properties.AsParallel();
    foreach (var one in allpro)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(one);
    }  
    var result = deviceInfo.Properties.TryGetValue("System.Devices.AudioDevice.Microphone.SignalToNoiseRatioInDb", out SignalToNoiseRatioInDb);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SignalToNoiseRatioInDb);
}
```

Comment: I can not correctly insert the id and for this it hangs to: await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync ()...

Comment: @Biro_20, Firstly please  learning the official sample I mentioned above to try to know how to get the device Id. When you run the scenario 2, you could find your device in the list with Id showed. Since this comment is complete a new issue,I'm afraid you should detail what you already have done in  your thread. Upload the code snippet you already did.

Comment: @Biro_20, I'm not mean put my code in your thread, avoid to do that. I mean did you try something before you ask this thread? The error above seems like it cannot find the device. Please try to find a correct device Id. It should be like `\\?\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.1.00000000}.{8...}`

Comment: @Biro_20, if you still cannot find the device Id, try search about "how to find the deviceid in uwp app". If you still cannot find out, try to ask a new thread with what  you have done.